# line graph by counts of each date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a line graph to see the overall trend of changes in count or frequency by date. Here is an example of my data (data_date).

I have tried the lines below but it returns errors
date is in date format and Freq is int

```
str(data_date)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data_date, aes(x=date())) +   
+   stat_count(geom='line', aes(y=Freq))
```

| date | Freq |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | 200 |
| 2022-05-02 | 300 |
| 2022-05-03 | 400 |
| 2022-05-04 | 500 |
| 2022-05-05 | 600 |

Comment: `date()` is a function call. This will return an error

Comment: also use `geom_line()` instead of the stat

Comment: hmm ok let me write the code again

Comment: If your `date` column is genuinely in date format, then the entire vode would be `ggplot(data_date, aes(date, Freq)) + geom_line()`

Answer (score 0):

Because you only have one observation per date, you need to use `group` in your `aes`. You can use the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data_date, aes(x=date, y = Freq, group = 1)) +   
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>